# Inserting Custom Auto-increment Field

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I need a query to insert an auto-increment field in the following format:

150001 (15 is last two digit of year 2015 and an id which increments like 0001, 0002, 0003 etc)

Till year 2016 March it need to show as 2015 only (15) after March it should change to 2016 (16). Because that's when our financial year ends. Is it possible to achieve the same with a query:

```
 150001
 150002
 160001 etc
```

Comment: ok this is simply an OCD issue. Why do you need this

Comment: why don't you simply do your inserts in a stored proc if this is so important

Comment: I need this so that users can understand so and so id's belong to so and so financial year.. 150001 means its 2015 financial years data.

Comment: just use second column with `15`

Comment: oh stored procedure is the only way? I have not worked in stored procedures..

Comment: then create a financialYear column. May I suggest an int

Comment: it is one way, not the only way

Comment: do you want me to write that stored proc for you? I will

Comment: It's business logic, not autoincrement, anyway, you always can to calc it from a date and standard autoincrement in your select queries

Comment: @Drew. Fine alright..meanwhile iam trying some other methods, but not sure

Comment: you really don't need 2016 to loop back to 1. It is silly !

Comment: @ Drew. Can u pls help me with the stored procedure.

Comment: sure. I have stooped to lower levels, but yes

Comment: @ vp_arth. That's what iam going to try now.

Comment: @vp_arth, any example query u can suggest to achieve this?

Comment: logic for march 2016 is `IF ELSE` condition only, i think you can do it by yourself :) you have to challenge your self , i modified my answer below for generation of id numbers to make it mysql syntax, my apologies awhile ago for using sql server syntax as i havent look at the tags :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah i will try to do the IF ELSE condition, but not sure if i can achieve the same..:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trick...

```
-->> 1st: Get the last 2 digit of the year
SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2);

-->> 2nd: Pad 4 digit zeros
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',1),4);

-->> 3rd: Concat the two query above, assuming that the column name is `ID_Column`
SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2), RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',ID_Column),4));
```

You can now insert the result of the 3rd query into your id.

**Note:** if your id is `integer`, you have to convert it into `varchar`

**sample:**

```
-->> Concat the two query above, replacing the column name value as 1
SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2), RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',1),4));

result: 150001
```

Comment: what server is this, sqlserver ?

Comment: @Japz..thank you for your time. But i have a small problem here with the year. Till year 2016 March it need to show as 2015 only (15) after March it should change to 2016 (16). Because that's when our financial year ends

Comment: You forget 2 things: March and 160001(reset the counter)

Comment: @Japz..also iam getting an error when iam running this in mysql.."#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL' "

Comment: @SanjuMenon , ah i see, my apologies .. you are using MySQL , you can remove the `ISNULL(ID_Column,' ')` and replace it by only column name `ID_Column`..

Comment: Is this the correct method " SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2) + RIGHT('0000' + 1,''),4) ;?

Comment: @SanjuMenon , ahm nope, here's the correct in MySQL `SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2), RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',1),4))`

Comment: @Drew , my apologies, i modified my answer to become MySQL

Comment: @SanjuMenon , i modified my answer above to make the syntax in mysql, awhile ago i used sql server.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like that(first assumption):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    IF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m')<3, 
        DATE_FORMAT(t.created, '%y')-1,
        DATE_FORMAT(t.created, '%y')),
    LPAD(
        id + 1 - (
            SELECT MIN(id) FROM Tbl t2 WHERE
            IF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m')<3, 
                DATE_FORMAT(t2.created, '%y')-1,
                DATE_FORMAT(t2.created, '%y')) =
            IF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m')<3, 
                DATE_FORMAT(t.created, '%y')-1,
                DATE_FORMAT(t.created, '%y'))
        ), 
        4, 
        '0') super_id
FROM Tbl t;
```

Comment: i certainly would not be generating my id's on the fly based on min and no locking.

Comment: I believe, much simpler to regenerate it on client side language(PHP/java/Delphi) while reports building :)

Comment: it is an id. id's are used in other tables. Your id's are volatile and the system goes casters up. Id's are not generated by reports

Comment: no reason to use `150007` id in the database at all. it's view representation

Comment: @vp_arth. What is this error which iam getting when iam trying to run this query in mysql. The error states that "#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'

Comment: I forgot `NOW()` see edit.. I can't to check this query, maybe there are tons of errors)

Comment: ok id's don't matter in this system. They aren't id's, they are line numbers to talk about on a report

Comment: @vp_arth. Iam getting the same error..:) Let me check it again

Comment: Don't use it in your production, it will very slow...  it's just an example

Comment: Again getting an error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4, 
        '0') super_id at line 15

Comment: Yes i understand, need an idea on how to achieve this, after that i can test a feasible method..

Comment: comma was missed. Why can't you to repair bug like this byself? No experience at all?

Comment: Still getting error only. Yeah basically iam a designer, trying to learn php, and mysql.. Let me try to rectify myself..:) Thank you for your time